# Python: UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, unicode, byte, websokets

Ребята помогите я уже устал)

client

```
import socket, threading, time,rsa
key = 9999

shutdown = False
join = False

def receving (name, sock):
    while not shutdown:
        #try:
            while True:
                data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
                #print(data)


                decrypt=rsa.decrypt(data.decode("utf-8"),rsa.PrivateKey())  # privatekey приватный ключь
                print(decrypt)

                # start 
                #decode text текст который нужно рашифровать
                #print("\n[*] Decrypted text:\n\n[text] << "+str(decrypt.decode("utf8"))+"\n")
                #end

                time.sleep(0.2)
        #except:
        #   pass
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 0


server = ('localhost', 9090)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.setblocking(0)

alias = input("Name: ")

rT = threading.Thread(target = receving, args = ("RecvThread",s))
rT.start()

while shutdown == False:
    if join == False:
        s.sendto(("["+alias + "] => join chat ").encode("utf-8"),server) #"["+alias + "] => join chat "
        join = True
    else:
        #try:
            message = input()   #Шифрование
            messagev2 = ("["+alias + "] :: " + message)
            #начало
            pub_key=int("") #Publickey публичный ключь
            text=messagev2.encode("utf8")
            crypt=rsa.encrypt(text,rsa.PublicKey(pub_key,65537)) # text message текст сообщения
            message = crypt
            if message != "":
                print(message)
                s.sendto(message,server) #s.sendto(("["+alias + "] :: "+message).encode("utf-8"),server)
            #конец
            time.sleep(0.2)
        #except:

        #   shutdown = True

rT.join()
s.close()
```

server

```
import socket, time

#host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 9090
#port = 5005
#sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
#sock.bind(('', UDP_PORT))

clients = []

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("",port))

quit = False
print("[ Server Started ]")

while not quit:
    #try:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)

        if addr not in clients:
            clients.append(addr)

        itsatime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S", time.localtime())

        print("["+addr[0]+"]=["+str(addr[1])+"]=["+itsatime+"]/",end="")
        print(data.decode("utf-8"))        


                    # .decode("utf-8") .декодировать ("utf-8")
                    # .encode("utf-8") .кодирование ("utf-8")

        for client in clients:
            if addr != client:
                s.sendto(data,client)
    #except:    
    #   print("\n[ Server Stopped ]")
    #   quit = True

s.close()
```

Ошибка на сервере

`print(data.decode("utf-8"))

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xac in position 6: invalid start byte`

Comment: Очевидно, ваш `data` не является текстом в кодировке utf-8, и пытаться его раскодировать так бессмысленно.

Comment: Попробуйте раскодировать в других кодировках.